# Some users receive email with no body

Tags: 7, emails

I have a Drupal 7 site with over 400 users. Time to time I use Mass contact to send updates to the users. I noticed that some of the users receives blank email with no body. I get no errors and there is noting on the logs. Not sure how to debug and solve the issue.

List of Modules

1. Mass Contact Version: 7.x-1.1
2. Mime Mail:Version: 7.x-1.1
3. Mail system: Version: 7.x-2.35

Configuration:

Mass Contact:

Maximum number of recipients before splitting up the email = 50

Send as BCC (hide recipients) by default =  is checked

Body text format = Full HTML (Wysiwyg - CKEditor)

Comment: Have you ever seen this with plain text format? I suspect that the HTML might be the culprit (though I have no evidence)

Side note ... hopefully you are using something like mailhog for testing so you dont spam your users.

Comment: @bleen thanks for the reply. I haven't test that without HTML will try that now. and thanks for the tip i have never used mailhog before something to learn now.

Comment: The [reroute email](https://www.drupal.org/project/reroute_email) module is also very useful if you need an in-Drupal solution